# return percentage per pair of items

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite and I have the following table:
[image]

and I have 2 goals:
The first is to return the IATA code of the airline that has the most bookings in first class.
I thought of this, but it doesn't quite work, it just returns all the airlines in no specific order:

```
select iata_code_airline
from booked_class_airline
group by class
having MAX(airline_class_count)
```

The second goal is to provide a column that shows the percentage of the total amount of passengers that travel in each class.
I tried:

```
SELECT class, 
       count(class) as class_count,
       count(class) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from booked_class_airline) as class_percent
FROM booked_class_airline
group by class
```

But this just counts the classes, not the count of the classes. I could use the airline_class count column, but then I don't know how to divide per class. Any advice?

Comment: My answer was originally marked as correct, but that has been rescinded. Just wondering what the issue is that led to the correct vote to have been removed?

Comment: No idea what happened but it was a mistake. Marked it as correct again. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your issues, I did the following (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d408ae83c05173ebc93307807b1de5d3)):

(Speaking of fiddles, it would be **far** better if you provided us with one (DDL and DML) along with your question - it eliminates duplication of effort and gives a [`single source of truth`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) - help us to help you! Also, please avoid using images for the reasons outlined in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)).

- Q1.  The first is to return the IATA code of the airline that has the most bookings in first class.

This is tricker than it might appear at first glance. A naive approach would be to do the following:

```
SELECT
  class, iata, MAX(cnt)
FROM flight
WHERE class = 'First'
GROUP BY class, iata
LIMIT 1;
```

Result:

```
class   iata    MAX(cnt)
First     BA           2
```

However, what happens when we do the following

```
INSERT INTO flight VALUES
('First', 'EI', 2);
```

and rerun our query?

Same result!!! But this is **wrong**! Or at least misleading, because we now have two airlines (`BA` **and** `EI`) with two bookings in first class! This demonstrates the perils of testing with a small (or in this case, minimal) amount of data!

Here, what we should do is this:

```
SELECT
  class, iata, MAX(cnt) AS c
FROM flight
WHERE class = 'First'
GROUP BY class, iata
HAVING MAX(cnt) = (
             SELECT 
               MAX(cnt) 
             FROM flight 
             WHERE class = 'First' 
           );
```

Result:

```
class   iata    c
First     BA    2
First     EI    2
```

Depending on your requirements, this **may** (and IMHO, probably **is**) better.

Finally, a third approach you might like to consider is using a [window function](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) (v. technical link - [this intro](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/) is excellent) - maybe a bit of overkill here, but window functions are **incredibly** powerful for more sophisticated queries and will repay any effort spent learning them 10 times over! The one I'm using in this instance is [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-dense_rank/) (from intro link).

```
SELECT 
  *,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS dr
FROM flight
WHERE class = 'First'
ORDER BY dr ASC;
```

Result:

```
class   iata    cnt     dr
First     BA      2     1
First     EI      2     1
First     SN      1     2
```

You can then wrap this is a sub-query (see fiddle) to pull out the first ranking airline(s). You may ask yourself why use this? Suppose your manager comes to you and says, I need the 3rd ranking airlines that have booked first class flights - v. tricky with "traditional" SQL - this makes it a doddle!

- Q.2 The second goal is to provide a column that shows the percentage of the total amount of passengers that travel in each class.

I've left some earlier steps to arrive here in the fiddle - running this:

```
SELECT
 class    AS "Class",
 SUM(cnt) AS "Total",
 ROUND(SUM(cnt) * 1.0/(SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM flight) * 100) AS "Percentage"
FROM flight
GROUP BY class;
```

Result:

```
Class   Total   Percentage
Business    4           31
Economy     4           31
First       5           38
```

You may be wondering why have a useless multiplication by 1 in the percentage calculation? This is to avoid problems with integer division - try taking it out - all the percentages drop to 0! I found this snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305613/converting-int-to-real-in-sqlite/8305623) - it's much more elegant - although perhaps a bit more puzzling than an explicit `CAST` - YMMV. +1 for the question for having provided me with a learning experience!

Comment: Q2 could be improved with a window function `SUM(cnt) * 1.0 / SUM(SUM(cnt)) OVER ()`

Comment: Seems you are right that SQLite doesn't like an aggregate inside a window function, but [you can subquery it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=32777fb553fbd03d15641ef83acf8855). Postgres fiddle is wrong because you are using `PARTITION` at the same time as `GROUP BY`, instead just use non-windowed `SUM(cnt)` divided by windowed `SUM(SUM(CNT)) OVER ()` see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b3a3c6a82da6d14aaca3cd6a7e9733d6). Not sure what you mean by perf penalty, I see none

Comment: If you run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` on `SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM flight;` and `SELECT SUM(SUM(cnt)) OVER ();` several times (in that order), the execution time for the latter always takes from 50% to 100% longer. AIUI, window functions (nearly?) always incur a performance penalty wrt [more conventional | earlier] ways of calculating the same thing. I see the point about using `PARTITION` at the same time as `GROUP BY` - schoolboy error... sometimes you stare at something you know should work... ah well, it was v. late last night - thanks for the clarification...

Comment: Apples/Oranges - in this case, the number arrived at is the same! Maybe I'm a bit obtuse, but I thought that you were telling me to use `SUM(SUM(cnt)) OVER ()` instead of `SELECT SUM(cnt)...` because it was more elegant... why did you suggest that the answer could be "improved" by using it so (really interested to know!)? Re. performance - if you look at row 11 for the 2nd query (last snippet in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ded39bd06125763b0028e851aee78f38) execution time), it **is** that one which I'm focusing on when I say that the time taken is 50-100% longer...

Comment: Apples and oranges because you weren't comparing your actual query, you were just comparing the single aggregation. Try this fiddle for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=44025a1b7bc77217931f37c9837eece6 and you see the execution time for the window aggregate is faster